# Can't input anything after the User obj3 = new User(); part

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i cannot input anything after the User obj3 part. Can anyone help me on what's wrong with it? i didn't know what to do already.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Administrator obj = new Administrator();
        
        
        System.out.print("Enter user ID: ");
        String userID = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Enter user password: ");
        int userPassword= input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter user Phone Number: ");
        long phoneNo = input.nextLong();
        
        Administrator obj1 = new Administrator(userID, userPassword);
        Administrator obj2 = new Administrator(userID, userPassword, phoneNo);
        
        User obj3 = new User();
        
        System.out.println("ID : ");
        String ID = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Password : ");
        int pass = input.nextInt();
        
        User obj4 = new User(ID,pass);
        
        
        if (userID == ID && userPassword==pass){
            System.out.print("Login succesfully!");
        }
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Do you need to add an ID ane a password to create a user `User obj3 = new User(someID,somePass);`? You also have a problem here `if (userID == ID && userPassword==pass)`, you can't use `==` to compare strings, you MUST use `oneStirng.equals(otherString)`, for example `if (userID.equals(ID) && userPassword.equals(pass))`

Comment: Check User class constructor there are parameters to be passed I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the way you used Scanner. I tried to run this myself (with User and Administrator commented out), and it skipped over the `ID:`  and `Password:`  inputs.

Scanner has a few catches to it. One of them is that `nextLong()` doesn't grab all the input from a line, only the first long it finds, separated by whitespace. Which means that the Scanner is still on the previous line when you call `nextLine()`. It just grabs the remainder of what is on the line when you fetched the phone number.

The easiest way to fix this would be to get rid of all of your `nextInt()` and `nextLong()`, and replace them with `nextLine()`. Once you have done that, use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the Strings that are outputted from `nextLine()` into Integers, or use `Long.parseLong()` to convert to Longs.

Also, you are comparing String like this.

`if (userID == ID && userPassword==pass)`

It might be better for you if you did it like this instead.

`if (userID.equals(ID) && userPassword==pass)`

Remember, `.equals()` is how you compare Strings (or any type of Object).

Comment: `.equals()` is not just a "formal" way of comparing strings, it is necessary to compare them using it, `==` does not compare them in a way anyone would expect. But in the code above userPassword is an int, so your code will not compile.

Comment: thank you so much @davidalayachew. problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it!